# What is the best and fastest way to browser receives many messages from the server?

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, browser, frontend

What is the best and fastest way to browser receives many messages from the server with background technology PHP? 
Is there something that is faster and better than AJAX? 
If there is not, which frequency of AJAX calls would be the most optimal? Is there some rule about it?

Comment: Look into web sockets http://socketo.me/

Comment: I don't know about the best way, but the fastest response times will be with sockets. As for the maximum frequency of AJAX calls, that'd really only depend on your server's cpu and bandwidth.

Comment: Depends on what are you making

Comment: Read more about AJAX and server side applications, sure PHP is a solution but not only one. Then confront that knowledge with your problem and you will have all answers you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  **COMET** will help you for this [check this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)  and other good methodes are  **AJAX-push** and **reverse-ajax.** 
**Comet** is basically an umbrella term for different ways of opening long-lived HTTP requests in order to push data in real-time to a web browser.

Tutorial [check this](http://ape-project.org/)

Comment: Thank you very much brother! :)  You helped me a lot with this tutorial.